# SQL union query issue

Tags: sql, select, union

What's wrong with the below code? I need it to combine between both select statements.

```
select  
    tt.SlpName, tt.Sum, tt.Duedate 
from
    (select  
         t3.docnum as 'Invoice', null as 'Receipt', 
         isnull(t6.SlpName, t6.SlpName) 'slpname', 
         null as 'Sum', null as 'Duedate'
     from 
         oitr t0
     inner join 
         ITR1 t1 on t0.ReconNum = t1.ReconNum
     inner join 
         ojdt t2 on t1.transid = t2.transid 
     inner join
         oinv t3 on  t3.docnum = t2.BaseRef and t1.IsCredit = 'D'
     inner join 
         oslp t6 on t3.slpcode = t6.SlpCode
     where 
         t1.ReconNum = '819272'

     union all 

     select 
         t4.docnum as 'Receipt', null as 'Invoice',
         'slpname', t5.checksum 'Sum', t5.DueDate 'Duedate' 
     from 
         oitr t0
     inner join 
         ITR1 t1 on t0.ReconNum = t1.ReconNum
     inner join 
         ojdt t2 on t1.transid = t2.transid 
     inner join 
         orct t4 on t4.docnum = t2.BaseRef  and t1.IsCredit = 'C'
     inner join 
         rct1 t5 on t5.docnum = t4.DocNum
     where 
         t1.ReconNum = '819272') tt
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZfPk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irU8i.png)

I want it to be like this

Thank you

Comment: What's wrong with it? Well, you tell us. Are you getting an error? If so which error message? Or are you not getting the rows you want? If so how are they different from what you expect?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? It often does make a difference whether you're using MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server or IBM DB2 - or something else even. Please add a relevant tag to your question!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `'slpname'` in your bottom query with `isnull(t6.SlpName,t6.SlpName)`
and add `inner  JOIN oslp t6 on t3.slpcode = t6.SlpCode`

Comment: It's not working , there is no table to join in the bottom select , the slpname is only available in the top select

Comment: Huumm you're right, didn't notice the absence of **oinv t3** 
Does t4 have a SPLNAME? If it doesnt I'm unable to build you a query that guesses the SPLNAME from the other query. If you know it always be the same you can try do it like this 'MySplname' as Splname